# automatic download with os detection

Tags: javascript, html, download

165/5000
I want to create a webpage with javascript that automatically detects which os the user has. and then download the correct installation file.

here is my code

html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <iframe id="my_iframe" style="display:none;"></iframe>
     <script src="os.js"></script> 
    </body>
</html>
```

javascript

```
var OSName = "Unknown OS";
if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("Win")!=-1) OSName="Windows";
if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("Mac")!=-1) OSName="MacOS";
if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("X11")!=-1) OSName="UNIX";
if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("Linux")!=-1) OSName="Linux";

if (OSName =  "Windows"){
    window.location = "https://test.leonwolvekamp.nl/TeamViewer_Setup.exe"


    };

if (OSName = "MacOS"){
     window.location = "https://test.leonwolvekamp.nl/TeamViewer.dmg"

    }


    };
```

But the download won't start

Comment: Ok, please explain what is the issue ?

Comment: The download won't start

Comment: For one, you're using `=` where you should be using `==`. Have you tested whether any of your `window.location = ...` lines are being executed? Have you looked at your console to see if there are any errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `if` statements only have one `=`. They need two. Also, you had an extra closing bracket. Try this code:

```
var OSName = "Unknown OS";
if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("Win")!=-1) OSName="Windows";
if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("Mac")!=-1) OSName="MacOS";
if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("X11")!=-1) OSName="UNIX";
if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("Linux")!=-1) OSName="Linux";

if (OSName ==  "Windows"){
    window.location = "https://test.leonwolvekamp.nl/TeamViewer_Setup.exe"
    };

if (OSName == "MacOS"){
     window.location = "https://test.leonwolvekamp.nl/TeamViewer.dmg"
    };
```

Comment: Thank you, that was the problem.